# Solve the equation $7\sin\theta+3\cos\theta=4$ for all solutions in the interval $0°\leq\theta\leq360°$, giving $\theta$ to the nearest $0.1°$

Tags: trigonometry

Using the Addition Formulae

\begin{align}
7\sin\theta+3\cos\theta & = 4 \\
\Rightarrow \sin(\theta+23.2°) & = \frac{4}{\sqrt{58}} \\ 
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\sin(\theta+23.2°) & = \frac{4}{\sqrt{58}} \\
\Rightarrow \theta+23.2° & = 31.7° \\ 
\Rightarrow \theta & = 31.7°-23.2° \\ 
\Rightarrow \theta & = 8.5° \\ 
\end{align}
Therefore the solutions are, $$\theta=8.5°$$
\begin{align}
\theta & = 180°-8.5° \\
\Rightarrow \theta & = 171.5° \\ 
\end{align}

The Mark Schemes solutions are,
$$\theta=8.5°$$
$$\theta=125.1°$$
Where have I gone wrong? I've noticed that the second solution of $\theta$ is equal to,
$$180-\left(\sin^{-1}\frac{4}{\sqrt{58}}\right)-23.2$$

but I cannot make any sense of this. Thanks

Comment: You almost get the right answer. You mistake is: if $sin(θ+23.2°)=a$, then $θ+23.2°=arcsin(a) or  θ+23.2°=180°-arcsin(a) $